# I delete qgis librarys manually, How can I install it again? in order to install qgis

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dependencies, qgis

I deled qgis librarys manually, How can I install them back again? in order to re install q gis

Good day Ubuntu Community!

I Used the comand rm -r in the root to delete the all qgis directories and relative documents for qgis (I means every thing in home that have qgis in the name e.g /usr/share/qgis , /usr/share/doc/qgis providers , /usr/share/doc/qgis providers-common , /usr/share/doc/lbqgis-3d3.10.6 , and so on directories, as well as: dir/share/doc/python3-qgis and so on ) in the hope to reinstall qgis because doesn't open. now I can't install qgis  because is imposible to install libgdal26 , libproj19 , grass783 and other packages because broken packages are held.

I already try to fix them using

```
apt-get update. ...
apt-get clean. ...
apt-get autoremove. ...
apt-get update –fix-missing. ...
dpkg –configure -a. ...
apt-get install -f.
```

I also tred to install the packages using synaptic but nothig work

If you are asking yourself why i did such a thing, well, because I assumed the re-installation of qgis will not have this kind of troubles, because isn't a common program. and after several "success" installations of qgis the program doesn't lanuch. in any case the mess is done.

Can any of you suggest any solutions? I'll like to avoid re-install ubuntu 18.04.3 from zero, or move up to ubuntu 20.

Thanks for read me.

Here are some output form the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que
usted pidió una situación imposible o, si está usando la distribución
inestable, que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se
han sacado de «Incoming».
La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 python-qgis : Depende: python3-qgis pero no va a instalarse
 qgis : Depende: libgdal26 (>= 2.3.0) pero no es instalable
        Depende: libqgis-analysis3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
        Depende: libqgis-app3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
        Depende: libqgis-core3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
        Depende: libqgis-gui3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
        Depende: python3-qgis (= 1:3.10.6+28bionic-ubuntugis) pero no va a instalarse
        Depende: qgis-providers (= 1:3.10.6+28bionic-ubuntugis) pero no va a instalarse
 qgis-plugin-grass : Depende: qgis-provider-grass (= 1:3.10.6+28bionic-ubuntugis) pero no va a instalarse
                     Depende: grass783 pero no es instalable
                     Depende: libgdal26 (>= 1.11) pero no es instalable
                     Depende: libqgis-app3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
                     Depende: libqgis-core3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
                     Depende: libqgis-gui3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
                     Depende: libqgisgrass7-3.10.6 pero no va a instalarse
E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

1) You have *held broken packages*. This means that you have introduced one or more wrong-version packages into your system. Usually, such packages come from a non-Ubuntu repository or PPA.

- You must uninstall ALL of the wrong-version packages.
- Best practice is also to remove the source that provides the wrong-version packages, else they will simply return to your system at the next upgrade.

2) You have removed files that were placed by the package manager. NEVER do that. Always use the package manager to remove files that it placed.

Apt does NOT monitor your system for file changes. It has no idea that you removed files. But now the system's reality does not match apt's understanding -- and that will eventually break your systems.

- You must tell apt to either remove or reinstall the package that provides the files you removed.

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall <package_name>
  // or //
  sudo apt remove --force <package_name>
  ```

That's a lot of self-inflicted damage. If you're not comfortable fixing BOTH problems, then backup your data (a good idea anyway!) and reinstall Ubuntu.